# Mozilla driver not able to run on the selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I am new to selenium, had a good time with chrome driver but Mozilla gecko driver keeps failing for some reason. Had googled a lot but no success.
Geco driver version is 0.31
Following is my simple code:

```
package com.selenium.practice.seleniumPractice;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class SeleniumFirstPractice {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "E:\\selenium\\geco\\geco\\geckodriver.exe");

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
    }

}
```

The error which I am getting is:

> SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
> SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation SLF4J:
> See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further
> details. 1659157780378    geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:59099
> Exception in thread "main"
> org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new
> session. Response code 500. Message: Expected browser binary location,
> but unable to find binary in default location, no
> 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no binary flag
> set on the command line Build info: version: '4.2.2', revision:
> '683ccb65d6' System info: host: 'LAPTOP-G0CNRTAM', ip: '192.168.99.1',
> os.name: 'Windows 11', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0',
> java.version: '11.0.14' Driver info:
> org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver Command: [null, newSession
> {capabilities=[Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName:
> firefox, moz:debuggerAddress: true, moz:firefoxOptions: {}}],
> desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true,
> browserName: firefox, moz:debuggerAddress: true, moz:firefoxOptions:
> {}}}]     at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:144)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:102)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:67)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:156)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:167)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:142)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:588)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:283)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:184)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:126)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:114)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:94)
> at
> com.selenium.practice.seleniumPractice.SeleniumFirstPractice.main(SeleniumFirstPractice.java:19)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am trying to use firefox gecko driver to open the facebook website. 
I have given my code, given the full error which I am getting. 
I have given brief information.